# What kind of storage for my webgis app

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, web-mapping, postgis-2.0

I'm making a WebGIS app where users will be able to upload and visualize the data on a 3D map (with Cesium). It will be DEM, DSM raster files. For this webGIS app I have a Nodejs server for all the logic and backend and a Tomcat server for GeoServer.

What I've tried :

Upload a .tif file directly from the app, the file is stored in AWS S3 bucket and then I store the metadata of the file in PostgreSQL (S3 URL's object, filename, date). But when I try to manually upload the file into GeoServer with the HTTPS URL of my AWS S3 bucket it doesn't work.

So, can I connect my AWS S3 buckets to GeoServer or maybe the PostgreSQL where the file URL is stored?

What kind of storage could be the best for my usage (PostgreSQL (PostGIS), cloud storage)?

Comment: Did you install the s3 extension?

Comment: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/s3-geotiff/index.html